# JavaScript variable output 1 but supposed to be 5

Tags: javascript

I've made a function and it checks a string for underscores and it adds to the variable "letter" each time it finds an underscore and I made a string with 5 but it only outputs 1.

```js
const test = function(words) {
  var letter = 1;
  for (var i in words) {
    if ("_" == i) {
      letter++;
      if (letter > 26) {
        letter = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(letter);
}

var word = "_____";
test(word);
```

Comment: `i` is not `_` as you expect, it's the index of the string. As such,  `letter` is never changing, as it's not entering the `if` true statement

Comment: you are using a `for in` loop instead of a `for of` loop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i in words <- this is used to access the indexes, inside if use as words[i]

correct code -

```
const test = function(words) {
    var letter = 1;
    for (var i in words) {
        if ("_" == words[i]) {
            letter++;
            if (letter > 26) {
                letter = 1;
            }
         }
    }
    console.log(letter);
}

var word = "_____";
test(word);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `for of` loop instead of a `for in` loop, because it only gives you the index not the value.

```
const test = function(words) {
  var letter = 1;
  for (var i of words) {
    if ("_" == i) {
      letter++;
      if (letter > 26) {
        letter = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(letter);
}

var word = "_____";
test(word);
```

## Update

If for some reason, you're not using a transpiler like babel and still want this to support in IE, you can use the following snippet:

```
const test = function(words) {
    var letter = 1;
    for (var i in words) {
        if ("_" == words[i]) {
            letter++;
            if (letter > 26) {
                letter = 1;
            }
         }
    }
    console.log(letter);
}
```

Comment: Note that this is not supported in IE.

Answer (score 0):

here is your fixed code first letter i start from 0 and o add `words.charAt(i)`

```js
const test = function(words) {
  var letter = 0;
  for (var i in words) {
    if ("_" == words.charAt(i)) {
      letter++;
      if (letter > 26) {
        letter = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(letter);
}

var word = "_____";
test(word);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be work as you expect.

```js
const test = function(words) {
  var letter = 0;
  for (var i in words) {
    if ("_" == words[i]) {
      letter++;
      if (letter > 26) {
        letter = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(letter);
}

var word = "_____";
test(word);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems wrong to me . You can check the below code :

```
const test = function(words) {
  var letter = 1;
  for (var i=0;i<words.length;i++) {
     console.log(words.charAt(i));
    if ("_" == words.charAt(i)) {
      letter++;
      if (letter > 26) {
        letter = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(letter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think condition 'letter > 26' might set letter back to 1.

```js
const test = function(words) {
  var letter = 1;
  for (var i in words) {
    if ("_" == words.charAt(i)) {
      letter++;
      if (letter > 26) {
        letter = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(letter);
}

var word = "_____";
test(word);
```